# Wordpress: Serve images from a CDN

Tags: wordpress, cdn

I use a CDN to serve my images, which I upload into Wordpress. My settings were:

[image]

It worked perfectly but it doesn't work anymore since I updated to Wordpress 4.5. This are my settings now:

[image]

This filter doesn't work either:

```
function my_cdn_upload_url() {
   return 'http://media.mydomain.com';
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_upload_url_path', 'my_cdn_upload_url' );
```

Does anyone know how should I serve my images from a CDN?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is editing the content of "upload_url_path" in the wp_options table:

```
upload_url_path > http://media.mydomain.com
```

Thank you!

Comment: Using this method displays all old uploaded media correctly but I can't upload any new media file; Do you have a similar issue?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you upgraded from quite an old WP version, didn't you? Uploads folder and path options were removed in Settings -> Media a long time ago.

So what does your real path for uploads look like? It's not a standard domain.com/wp-content/uploads// correct?
If yes - where do new images get uploaded to after the upgrade?

Try playing around with https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-upload-dir/ and see if it helps get your images back to CDN.

Comment: No, I just updated from 4.4 to 4.5. I read that these settings were removed since 3.5 but I've got different installs with 4.4 and they still show these options. Don't ask me why...  My real path is normal one with date. My CDN is AWS cloudfront and reads the origin from wp-content/uploads/2016/...  I want to replace mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/ to images.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/

Comment: In a nutshell: create a subdomain, change upload path in the database, redirect old path to new path. It's nicely described here: http://www.dezzain.com/wordpress-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-uploads-path-to-subdomain/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the approaches above are you won't have file write permissions to upload images to your CDN.

Another approach is to upload all of your images to somewhere - e.g. Amazon S3, or keep them on affiliate network CDNs - and then store your image URLs in postmeta for your posts or products.

You then need to alter your theme files to pull the images from the postmeta fields instead of from the featured image or thumbnail fields.

FYI - this approach will *massively* speed up imports since WordPress will create multiple sizes of images using up CPU and disk space.

I created a plugin to solve this:

https://www.wpintense.com/product/external-images/

Comment: My solution is based on AWS Cloudfront, which automatically reads and writes files in their CDN servers as long as they exist in the origin path.

Comment: That sounds pretty cool actually. How does it handle write permissions? You whitelist the server IP address or something?

Comment: No, you just need 2 subdomains. First one is the origin subdomain and should point to your images folder. The second one points to the origin subdomain:

img-origin.yourdomain.com > A >188.95.253.55
img.yourdomain.com > CNAME > a1hysdadp83zeqq0.cloudfront.net

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden admin page where you can find all the options:

```
http://localhost/wp-admin/options.php
```

Find the `upload_url_path` option and set a value.

[image]

---

Note:

After you give it value, then the "Store uploads in this folder" which is the `upload_path`, and "Full URL path to files" which is the `upload_url_path` options will also appear on the Media Settings page:

```
http://localhost/wp-admin/options-media.php
```

[image]

The options only appear on the Media Settings page if a value is already set. This is the code in WordPress Core that defines how it works:

```php
/*
 * If upload_url_path is not the default (empty),
 * or upload_path is not the default ('wp-content/uploads' or empty),
 * they can be edited, otherwise they're locked.
 */
if ( get_option( 'upload_url_path' ) || get_option( 'upload_path' ) && 'wp-content/uploads' !== get_option( 'upload_path' ) ) :
```

Answer (score -1):

BEST WAY is to use w3 total cache.

It has a built in cdn support and of course you can use it's main functionality , caching , most useful to speedup website.

Comment: Thank you but I would prefer not using it. The less plugins, the better. For the moment, Varnish and memcached is enough for me.